# Toolbar overlaps status bar

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I've got a problem with my status bar which gets overlapped by the toolbar.

I wanted to have the function that when the user scrolles the `ListView` down, the toolbar disappears behind the status bar so that only the tabs are visible, just like in the WhatsApp and YouTube apps.

To achieve this effect or to get this function I used this line:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

into my `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, but know as I said before, the status bar gets overlapped by the toolbar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thankful for any help!

UPDATE:

v21\styles.xml

```
<resources>>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the style this activity is using from your styles.xml

Comment: @asadmshah I updated my post

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` or `@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay` style

Comment: now i've got the effect that i wanted, but my Notification bar turned white @mdtuyen

Comment: you can use `setStatusBarColor(int color)` in code or change style to fix it

Comment: I already found another way 
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> is that okey or will I have any problems with that? @mdtuyen

Comment: it's not working in android 4.4 series android devices, what solutions you can suggest? @phongvan

Answer (score 3):

in `v21\styles.xml`

remove 
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me to get a white overlay on device status bar (problem after update in question)

I changed:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

in my styles.xml file

Comment: In my case it changed a normal color of status bar to black.

Comment: @CoolMind see this [link](http://matthewwear.xyz/no-excuses-it-takes-5-mins-make-that-drawer-visible-under-your-status-bar-2/)
it describes how it works in details

Comment: official Docs on same topic : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds

Comment: thanks, I know this (has been making an app for several month), but your link is useful.

Answer (score 0):

try making `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` for  `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`