# Tablayout overlapping toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to use `Tablayout` with `Toolbar` but it's giving me like the image below, and when try to remove `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` from `v21\styles.xml` the Toolbar being overlapped by the android system status bar

[image]

`v21\styles.xml`

```
<resources>



<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>

</style>



<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">@color/popColorBg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
</style>
```

`activity.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimaryFab"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDarkFab"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorPrimaryDarkFab" />
```

And according to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33985417/3005903) if I'll do this and remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `v21\styles.xml` my layout will be like this:

[image]

Comment: `from v21\styles.xml the Toolbar being overlapped by the android system status bar` But it's working on +21 api right? have you tried adding this line in `AppBarLayout` and no styles? : `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`